# Unique Records using a subset of columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a series of dynamic array formulas for processing data. I'm trying to get the last piece sorted out.

I have data that resembles this:

[image]

I want to return data that looks like this:

[image]

The columns highlighted in **green** are being used as a **key column** for **distinct records**. For the remaining columns I'm just taking the **first record**.

These formulas are already a little unwieldy, so I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't add too much complexity.

Comment: If you want the least complex solution that won't slow down your workbook, you could just use a pivot table

Answer (score 2):

Try something along the lines:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A10</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _delimited, A2#&"|"&B2#&"|"&D2#&"|"&E2#,
     _label4, XLOOKUP(_delimited,_delimited,C2#),
     _label5, XLOOKUP(_delimited,_delimited,F2#),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2#,B2#,_label4,D2#,E2#,_label5)))
```

---

- `_delimited` --> Arrays `A2#`, `B2#`, `D2#` & `E2#` are concatenated with a delimited `|` to avoid `FALSE POSITIVES`
- `_label4` --> Returns the array `C2#` --> which is gives the first match from the dupes.
- `_label5` --> Returns the array `F2#` --> likewise as `lable4`
- Finally, merged and wrap within in `UNIQUE()` function to exclude the dupes.

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A10</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _delimited, A2#&"|"&B2#&"|"&D2#&"|"&E2#,
     _label4_5, INDEX(HSTACK(C2#,F2#),XMATCH(_delimited,_delimited),{1,2}),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2#,B2#,TAKE(_label4_5,,1),D2#,E2#,DROP(_label4_5,,1))))
```

---

Comment: Bit shorter version for the 2nd method: `=LET(_delimited, A2#&"|"&B2#&"|"&D2#&"|"&E2#,UNIQUE(INDEX(HSTACK(A2#,B2#,C2#,D2#,E2#,F2#),XMATCH(_delimited,_delimited),SEQUENCE(,6))))`

Comment: upvoted - you can use `A2#:F2#` instead of `HSTACK(A2#,B2#,C2#,D2#,E2#,F2#)`, thereby saving one function

Comment: @SpectralInstance Ah great catch!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data start in cell `A1`

[image]

you could use the formula

```
=LET(rng,A2#&B2#&D2#&E2#,unq,UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2#,B2#,D2#,E2#)),_1,TAKE(unq,,2),_2,TAKE(unq,,-2),lkp,INDEX(_1,,1)&INDEX(_1,,2)&INDEX(_2,,1)&INDEX(_2,,2),
HSTACK(_1,XLOOKUP(lkp,rng,C2#),_2,XLOOKUP(lkp,rng,F2#)))
```